# Loading registry hive is not remembered: where to start searching for errors?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry

I'm trying to load a couple of registry .DAT files as Hives under HKLM.

The .DAT files come from a Windows Server 2008 system and I'm trying to locally reproduce some software development issue.

I've tried this in multiple directories (some under directories in `C:\Program Files (x86)`, and under `C:\Windows\system32\config`).

The .DAT files load fine in Regedit when I run that as an Administrator.
After that, I can read/write the registry keys fine when running the app as Administrator, and from Regedit.

However, the loaded hives do not persist: after a reboot they are not loaded any more.

The odd thing is: no error messages in the `EventVwr.exe` that seem to be relevant.

Where should I look for errors and causes of this?

And if this is not a bug, how can I force the loading of these hives at boot time?

Comment: That's not a bug; it's the expected behavior.

Comment: @AaronMiller any documentation about this? Is there a way to work around it?

Comment: @JeroenWiertPluimers: Your question assumes that there is documentation to support your method.  I know of no documentation that says your method is supported.